# CriteriaQuery for different Entities

Tags: java, jpa

I have a very basic question but cant find the correct solution. I would like to read all records of a JPAEntity using a CriteriaQuery having only a reference  to the class of the JPAEntity respectively it should work for defferent JPAEntites.

The folowing Code works and it does what I want:

```
private void test(Field jpaField) {
    List l;
    final Class c = jpaField.getType();

    final CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(c);
    criteriaQuery.select( criteriaQuery.from( c ) );
    l = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();

    ...
}
```

But I get many warnings concerning type safty. I tried the following correction to solve this problem while staying generic:

```
private void test(Field jpaField) {
    List<?> l;
    final Class<?> c = jpaField.getType();

    final CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(c);
    criteriaQuery.select( criteriaQuery.from( c ) );
    l = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();

    ...
}
```

But now I get errors about unmatching types. I think I have to ensure somehow that createQuery(c) and from(c) use the same type. But I dont know how. Does anyone know how to use this pattern correctly?

Thank you for any hint.

Best regards, Dominic

Comment: But a `Field` is not an `Entity`?

Comment: You are right there is something missing in the explanation: The jpaField in this example is a ManyToOne Field pointing to an other entity. Therefore jpaField.getType() and as consequence the variable c are a JPA-Entity. You can forget the Field and just take the Class c as a  JPA-Entity class.. sorry for that. As wirtten: The code works as long as I dont try to specify types but with warnings ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was pointed out, the signature of a generic `findAll` method is

```
<T> List<T> findAll(Class<T> entity)
```

I think the tricky part to conceptualize is the `Class<T> entity`. But, if you look at the signature of `createQuery` you'll see it's basically the same:

```
<T> CriteriaQuery<T> createQuery(Class<T> resultClass)
```

So a generic `findAll` method is written like so:

```
public <T> List<T> findAll(Class<T> entity) {
    CriteriaQuery<T> q = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(entity);
    q.select(q.from(entity));
    return em.createQuery(q).getResultList();
}
```

Used like so:

```
findAll(entity.getClass());
```

You can't pass a generic method the entity itself because it is a runtime object and generics are compile time constraints.

Comment: "You can't pass a generic method the entity itself because it is a runtime object and generics are compile time constraints." I know that and thats exactely my problem because I dont have the class at design time! It must be possible to do this without warnings..

Answer (score 0):

It's a methode desgin question. Perhaps you can call the getType() outside your methode?

```
 private <T> List<T> test(Class<T> jpaFieldClass) ....
```

Comment: I never have a specific Entity-Class at design-time therefore it is not possible to encapsulate the code as a generic. The issue is not about where I get the Entity-Class from - it is: if I have a entity-class from somewhere how can I read all records using a CriteriaQuery without warnings ...